# How do I correctly write distance?

Tags: abbreviations, measuring-units, spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it appropriate to use non-breaking spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28467/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-non-breaking-spaces)

If I am writing "I ran X distance", should I leave a space between the value and abbreviated distance, or is it more appropriate to bunch them together:

a) "I ran 5km"

b) "I ran 5 km"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention in technical contexts may be different, but my own practice it so to insert a space after the numeral, and show that it's plural: *I ran 5 kms*.

Comment: Thank you - is this an international standard?

Comment: I shouldn't think so. There aren't any international standards governing such things. It's just a matter of the custom and practice in different places.

Comment: The correct symbol for kilometres is *km.* *kms* is kilometre-second, a unit which is meaningless. "I ran 5 km" is correct. "5 kms" is not. You do need the non-breaking space between *5* and *km*, and it's a pity that comments don't allow that (but do demonstrate the necessity nicely).

Comment: I dont think you need the *s* at the end.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I'd be interested to know if you have a source for that.

Comment: Most easily found: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units "Symbols of units are not pluralised; e.g., '25 kg', not '25 kgs'.[20]" Citation 20 is http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf published by the International Bureau of Weights and Measures 2006.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Thank you. I have amended my answer, but will persist in my own wayward practice.